# Angular2, How to use JSON data in service.ts?

Tags: angular

todo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

    public todos
    constructor(private http:Http) { }
    getDatas(){
        this.http.get('../json/test_data.json')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => {this.todos = data},
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done')
        );
    }
    get(query = ''){
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        var data;
        var todos = this.getDatas();
        console.log("todos ================== " + todos)
        if(query === 'completed' || query === 'active'){
          var isCompleted = query === 'completed';
        //   data = todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isCompleted);
        } else {
          data = todos;
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    }
}
```

todo.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css'],
  providers: [TodoService]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

    private todos;
    private activeTasks;
    private newTodo;
    private path;

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    getTodos(query = ''){
      return this.todoService.get(query).then(todos => {
        this.todos = todos;
        // this.activeTasks = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone).length;
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.path = params['status'];
            this.getTodos(this.path);
        });
    }
}
```

I think, If i use "`getDatas(){...getJSON...}`" 
I can get this data from "test_data.json" file.
and i think, i can put this data to "`this.getDatas();`"

But when i use "`console.log("todos ================== " + todos)`" in todo.service.ts file, Result is "undefined".

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't switch back from async execution to sync execution.
If you want to execute code after data from an async call arrived, you **always** have to chain the calls (`then`, `map`, ...):

```
getDatas(){
  return this.http.get('../json/test_data.json') // <<< return the observable
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .map( // <<<=== instead of subscribe
        data => {
          this.todos = data; // <<< might not be necessary (done at caller site as well)
          return data;
        } //,
        // err => console.error(err), // <<< use catch if you need to handle errors here
        // () => console.log('done') // <<< use finally if you need to do something when the request is completed
    );
}
get(query = ''){
    // var data; // <<< redundant
    return this.getDatas().map(todos => 
      console.log("todos ================== " + todos)
      if(query === 'completed' || query === 'active'){
        var isCompleted = query === 'completed';
        return data = todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isCompleted);
      } else {
        return todos;
      }
    });
}
```

```
getTodos(query = ''){
  return this.todoService.get(query).subscribe(todos => {
    this.todos = todos;
    // this.activeTasks = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone).length;
  });
}
```

Comment: I wrote this code, and there was no error message. but, Nothing happened.
I can't see the console message.

Comment: Can't imagine that "nothing" happens.  You don't get any console output?

Comment: I just get this message "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."

Comment: I updated the `get` method and added changes for `getTodos`

Comment: I got 2 issues,
get(query = ''){
    // var data; // <<< redundant
    return this.getDatas().subscribe(todos => 
      console.log("todos ================== " + todos)
      if(query === 'completed' || query === 'active'){      <<<<<here
        var isCompleted = query === 'completed';
        return data = todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isCompleted);
      } else {
        return todos;
      }
    }); <<<<<here
}

Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: So i changed this code

get(query = ''){
    // var data; // <<< redundant
        return this.getDatas().subscribe(todos =>{
          console.log("todos ================== " + todos)
          if(query === 'completed' || query === 'active'){
            var isCompleted = query === 'completed';
            //return data = todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isCompleted);
          } else {
            return todos;
          }
        });
    }

Comment: And did this help?

Comment: After that I got this error message : Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. in "todo.component.ts" file.

Comment: Sorry, forget to change `subscribe` to `map` in `get()`

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)