# How to display data from local Json file?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, Trying to build a movie app.

I want to fetch data from JSON file which is on my local machine. I can display all the movies from the JSON file in the MovieListComponent. But When the user clicks on the view detail of a particular movie I am not able to display the data in the MovieDetail component.

**MovieListComponent.ts**

```js
import {Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from '../services/movie.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Movie} from '../movie';
@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,  
  templateUrl: 'search.html',
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit { 
  movies:Movie[];
  constructor(
              private _movieservice:MovieService, 
              private router:Router ){  
              } 
  getMovies():void{
    this._movieservice.getMovies().then(movies => this.movies = movies);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMovies();
  }  
  onSelect(movie:Movie):void{
    this.router.navigate(['/movies',movie.id]);
    console.log(movie.title);
  } 
}
```

**MovieDetailComponent.ts**

```js
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute,Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {MovieService} from '../services/movie.service';
import {Movie} from '../movie';

@Component({
    template:`<div *ngIf="movie">
                {{movie.title}}
                <h4>You're seleted departmentId is =  {{movie.id}} </h4>
             </div>`
})

export class ViewDetailComponent implements OnInit{

  movie:Movie;

  constructor(
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private movieservice:MovieService,
    private location:Location){}

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params:Params) => this.movieservice.getMovie(+params['id'] ))
    .subscribe(movie => this.movie = movie);    
  }
}
```

**MovieService.ts**

```js
import{Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Movie} from '../movie';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService{
    private movieUrl = './app/movies.json';
    constructor(private _http:Http){
        console.log('Movie Service up and running');
    }
    getMovies():Promise<Movie[]>{      
        return  this._http.get(this.movieUrl)
        .toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Movie[]);
        //.map(res => res.json());
    }
    getMovie(id: number):Promise<Movie>{
       // const url = `${this.movieUrl}/${id}`;
        return this._http.get(this.movieUrl)
        .toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Movie)  
    }
}
```

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620548/angular2-how-to-use-json-data-in-service-ts?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are casting the movies.json to a single movie:

```
getMovie(id: number):Promise<Movie[]>{
  return this._http.get(this.movieUrl)
  .toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Movie[] /* Error here */)
}
```

Instead you need to either get a single movie, or search through the movies and return a single one with the given ID:

```
getMovie(id: number):Observable<Movie>{
    return this._http.get(this.movieUrl)
        .map(response => { return <Movie>(<Movie[]>response.json())
        .find((item: Movie) => item.id == id));
}
```

Comment: i tried but getting an error `[ts] Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.
`

Comment: Updated to remove the .toPromise. You don't need it as the .get returns an observable, and find returns a single movie. I changed the signature to Observable<Movie>. I also recommend you develop with  your developer tools to the console tab, you will see the errors you are getting.

Comment: i've imported observable from rxjs/Rx but i'm getting following error in console `this._http.get(...).subscribe(...).find is not a function`

Comment: No need to subscribe here, just map the response, cast it to Movie[] and then find the single item. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Angular-CLI`, you need to add json file to assets folder. and then reference from there.

If not you have to make sure that your web server is serving the json file and use from there.

Comment: If you want to serve your files other than assets folder than you can put that folder in src folder and make entry for the same in the list of assets in .angular-cli.json file

Comment: Working for me! ;)